# how to insert different data type in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am migrating data from old database  to new database.few columns are having different datatype. like instead of float ,decimal is there in new db. 
my query is below but its giving error :

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric.
```

is there any way to insert all data without any problem

**Query :**

```
insert into [newdb].[dbo].[newtab](State,StationID,AlertLevel,WarningLevel,DangerLevel,NormalLevel,UpperWaterLevel,LowerWaterLevel,WaterLevel_StationCode,RainFall_StationCode,OneHourRainfall,TwoHourRainFall,FourHourRainfall,TwantyFourHourRain,Lattitude,Longitude,District,RiverBasin,StationType)
Select State,Station_Name,ALERT,WARNING,DANGER,NORMAL,UPPER_WL,LOWER_WL,STID_WL,STID_RF,RF1HR,RF2HR,RF4HR,RF24HR,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,DISTRICT,RIVER_BASSIN,StType from [olddb].[dbo].oldtab;
```

**Datatypes**:

**Olddb**

```
STATE   varchar(50)
STATION_NAME    varchar(50)
MMIID   int
STATION_ID  int
ALERT   float
WARNING float
DANGER  float
NORMAL  float
MAX_WL  float
MAIN_ID int
UPPER_WL    float
LOWER_WL    float
STID_WL int
STID_RF int
RF1HR   float
RF2HR   float
RF4HR   float
RF24HR  float
LATITUDE    decimal(7, 6)
LONGITUDE   decimal(9, 6)
REAL_NAME   varchar(50)
DISTRICT    varchar(50)
RIVER_BASSIN    varchar(50)
position_wl int
station_status  int
position_rf int
FULLNAME    varchar(70)
station_update  int
rainfall_name   varchar(70)
TIMESTAMPS  smalldatetime
Lembangan   int
StType  varchar(50)
```

**Newdb**

```
ID  int
StationID   varchar(50)
StationName varchar(100)
District    varchar(50)
RiverBasin  varchar(50)
CrossSectionID  varchar(50)
LastUpdate  datetime
State   varchar(50)
CreatedBy   varchar(50)
CreationDate    datetime
Deletedby   varchar(50)
DeletionDate    datetime
Lattitude   decimal(9, 6)
Longitude   decimal(9, 6)
Status  bit
OneHourRainfall int
TwoHourRainFall int
FourHourRainfall    int
TwantyFourHourRain  int
NormalLevel decimal(7, 2)
AlertLevel  decimal(7, 2)
WarningLevel    decimal(7, 2)
DangerLevel decimal(7, 2)
StationType varchar(50)
WaterLevelParameter varchar(1)
NormalMin   decimal(7, 2)
NormalMax   decimal(7, 2)
ModerateMin decimal(7, 2)
ModerateMax decimal(7, 2)
HeavyMin    decimal(7, 2)
HeavyMax    decimal(7, 2)
RainfallParameter   varchar(1)
UpperWaterLevel decimal(7, 2)
LowerWaterLevel decimal(7, 2)
PostWL  decimal(7, 2)
PostRF  decimal(7, 2)
FlowParameter   varchar(1)
RainFall_StationCode    varchar(50)
WaterLevel_StationCode  varchar(50)
Flow_StationCode    varchar(50)
StationStatus   varchar(10)
WaterLevelStation   varchar(10)
ImageName   varchar(50)
ModifyBy    varchar(50)
ModifyDate  datetime
Spike15MinWL    decimal(7, 2)
Spike1HrWL  decimal(7, 2)
RainfallHigh    decimal(7, 2)
```

Comment: perhaps you should read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Comment: @lc. no columns are equal in select and insert statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is arising because the data type in your new db is not big enough.There are 2 ways to go about this:

1. Find the max value of the float/decimal/int fields in the old database and make sure the data types in the new database are sufficient.
2. Increase your decimal columns in your new db to a sufficiently higher type, say to decimal 18,4 if they are now 6,2 or 9,2. After you are done with migration, you can scale back.